# Hide a div using css in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

This is the html of what I want to hide

```
<div class="count">
            <div class="number">1</div>
            <div class="text">donation</div>
        </div>
```

I've tried to use the CSS code:

```
.count {
  display: none;
}
```

As well as:

```
body.page-id-750 div.count {
  display: none;
}
```

For ref the body is:

```
<body itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope="itemscope" class="page-template-default page page-id-750 logged-in admin-bar wp-custom-logo ast-single-post ast-mobile-inherit-site-logo ast-inherit-site-logo-transparent ast-theme-transparent-header ast-hfb-header ast-page-builder-template ast-no-sidebar astra-3.9.2 elementor-default elementor-kit-442 elementor-page elementor-page-750 customize-support e--ua-blink e--ua-chrome e--ua-webkit ast-mouse-clicked ast-header-break-point"
```

Comment: `.count{display:none;}` should work, you can inspect your element to see if it's applied (no : cache ? wrong css file ?). If it is, is it overridden ?

Comment: are you working local or on a host. if on a host send me the URL i'll look into it;.

Comment: its https://maskun.org/donate/

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
.count {
  display: none!important;
}

body.page-id-750 div.count {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: nope, I tried both of these and it doesn't work

Comment: This should work.
Since you are working with wordpress, you can try a plugin to add css on your website. Such as Simple CSS plugin.

Here, you should be able to add the code above and override the .css files. 

Good luck with it!

Comment: yeah, I used Simple CSS Plugin

Comment: @ValentinaFurnò For custom CSS WordPress doesn't need a plugin. Just navigate to `Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

I looked add you website code and the problem is that you are loading a widget thats an **iframe**.

In basic an iframe is an element to show an other website inside your website. Your website doesn't control the iframe content.

Now the strange part is if i look add the iframe you are loading it with code from your own website? So the solution would be adding the css to your widget or iframe.

Is there a widget or plugin you are using?

Comment: yes, i'm using a plugin, but where do I go to access the CSS for the plugin?

Comment: There for you should read the documentation of the plugin, or aks support from the Plugin creators. Without information about the plugin it's hard for the community to help you.